# Cannot delete SQS Message using Dotnet Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, serverless

I have spent nearly 6 hours and searched all over google and I can't seem to find what I am doing wrong. I have created a Lambda function using the dotnet framework and it's triggered by an SQS standard queue. After processing a message I want to delete it from the queue so that it isn't picked up again. My code is:

```
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using Amazon.Lambda.SQSEvents;
using Amazon.Runtime;
using Amazon.SQS;
using Amazon.SQS.Model;

[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))]

namespace AWSLambda1;

public class Function
{
    public Function()
    {
    }

    public async Task FunctionHandler(SQSEvent evnt, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        foreach (var message in evnt.Records)
        {
            if (ProcessMessage(message))
                await DeleteMessage(message, context);
        }

    }

    private static bool ProcessMessage(SQSEvent.SQSMessage message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\nMessage body of {message.MessageId}:");
        Console.WriteLine($"{message.Body}");
        return true;
    }

    private static async Task DeleteMessage(SQSEvent.SQSMessage message, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        var sqsClient = new AmazonSQSClient();
        var qUrl = "https://sqs.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXXXXX/TestQueue";

        try
        {
            context.Logger.LogInformation($"\nDeleting message {message.MessageId} from queue...");
            context.Logger.LogInformation($"\nReceipt Handle: {message.ReceiptHandle}");

            var deleteReq = new DeleteMessageRequest
            {
                QueueUrl = qUrl,
                ReceiptHandle = message.ReceiptHandle
            };

            var deleteResp = await sqsClient.DeleteMessageAsync(deleteReq);

            // This block of code is never reached
            context.Logger.LogInformation($"\nDeleted message {message.MessageId} from queue...");
            context.Logger.LogInformation($"\nDeleted message with status {deleteResp.HttpStatusCode}");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            context.Logger.LogInformation($"\nEXCEPTION ON DELETE MESSAGE {e.Message} from queue...");
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

I extracted this code from the AWS website and I have tried everything. There are no errors in the log files. This is a sample from the logs:

```
2022-06-28T22:30:19.441+03:00   START RequestId: c86729c3-5df9-57b0-8b46-72f6050fae56 Version: $LATEST
2022-06-28T22:30:19.805+03:00   2022-06-28T19:30:19.748Z c86729c3-5df9-57b0-8b46-72f6050fae56 info
2022-06-28T22:30:19.805+03:00   Message body of 9a99b479-66f5-4740-afb5-6dc9693e5907:
2022-06-28T22:30:19.805+03:00   2022-06-28T19:30:19.805Z c86729c3-5df9-57b0-8b46-72f6050fae56 info test
2022-06-28T22:30:20.425+03:00   2022-06-28T19:30:20.425Z c86729c3-5df9-57b0-8b46-72f6050fae56 info
2022-06-28T22:30:20.425+03:00   Deleting message 9a99b479-66f5-4740-afb5-6dc9693e5907 from queue...
2022-06-28T22:30:20.425+03:00   2022-06-28T19:30:20.425Z c86729c3-5df9-57b0-8b46-72f6050fae56 info
2022-06-28T22:30:20.425+03:00   Receipt Handle: AQEBH/vZmNFFir4oshRJxMGtOAAuu+KcboUqRnFWNCseksSAT+ShxslAaRJP1BoDk6L+3iSvMoxdRUcspHCfY40hZumCZvJnuD8U0IEOG6jwRMdORjP7oTpdsRoV/ZloAQL5tJzlK/jRHRWlsTPr1n1IpkS4sXgPnD8fxrW0OiG3ARX/N/ii1RsWLMZnc4tgYFpGicuKdT0/EzdUonenTwDut4KHQVZWbu4nisqc6y2IyyhZwOXyfzLoc7Jk+DeCulRZPpcPRUk1qeUoLExc3fSnFukMtizm8i2to82OaKqkc27ZFyXRGQzEChL5ed/Z1RRPTUlSt/qzgjye2IXhvU2u6piZ/kFpV4v7+3tQ2Ts1oMCs5M+HiONS1wVlqlpGzAunSDmpaXtZF+7HAk97LeYPPg==
2022-06-28T22:30:49.451+03:00   END RequestId: c86729c3-5df9-57b0-8b46-72f6050fae56
```

As you can see, the last two logging lines in the `DeleteMessage` function are not executed. I would appreciate anyone who can point me in the right direction to figure out why this won't delete any messages. Thanks!

Comment: My guess is you are running it in a VPC without a route to a NAT Gateway or an SQS VPC Endpoint. Although, you know you can just return a success code from your function and Lambda will delete the messages for you right?

Comment: You raise a very important point @MarkB. Let me check this.

Comment: No luck. Function is in a VPC with an Internet Gateway. And I tried returning a success but the message was not deleted.

Comment: A Lambda function in a VPC cannot use an Internet Gateway directly, because it does not have a public IP address. That's why I specifically stated it would need a NAT Gateway, or a SQS VPC endpoint. Of course if you don't actually need to access VPC resources with this function then you should remove it from the VPC.

Comment: I see. Thanks for that. Makes sense. Let me do some digging!

Comment: @MarkB your comments led me to the answer. Indeed adding the Lambda to the VPC required me to edit some security  rules so that the lambda can access the other services. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

If your Lambda function is triggered by an Amazon SQS message, then you should *not* delete the message from Amazon SQS. The AWS Lambda service will do this for you.

When the Lambda function is invoked, it will be passed the message in the `SQSEvent`. Your function should process the message. Then, if processing is successful, your function should exit without throwing an exception. The AWS Lambda service will then delete the SQS message automatically.

As a result, your function does not actually require access to a VPC or the Internet to correctly process the message.